# Best way to display Prometheus histograms in Grafana?

Tags: histogram, prometheus, grafana, promql

I have a metric histogram that's supposed to measure how long a certain operation took. It'll get reported multiple times a second, and the buckets are set to be 10ms, 50ms, 100ms, 500ms, 1s, 2s

I'd like to achieve the following visuals in Grafana:

1. Be able to trend as a line the raw metric samples reported. Do histograms track the raw values? essentially trend them as if it was a gauge.
2. Visualize the buckets on the y-axis over time on the x-axis.
3. Visualize the buckets on the x-axis and the count of samples within those buckets on the y-axis.

I can't seem to get (1) using Time series panel in Grafana, using something like:

```
sum(rate(my_metric_sum[$__rate_interval]))/sum(rate(my_metric_count[$__rate_interval]))
```

The values I get do not make sense.

For (2) I tried using a Heatmap panel, but I'm not convinced with the values I see somehow:

```
sum(rate(my_metric_bucket[$__rate_interval])) by (le)
```

If anyone out there has cracked the mystery of understanding histograms in Prometheus and visualizing them in Grafana would appreciate your input.

Comment: Query for (1) is the correct one. In (2), you probably want a `increase` instead of `rate`. (3) isn't clear what you want, but probably something like same query ad (2), type of query *Instant* and bar chart

Comment: And regarding you question itself: you have three unrelated questions here. It will be closed as unfocused. For this to be within guidelines of SO it should be three separate questions.

Comment: https://grafana.com/blog/2020/06/23/how-to-visualize-prometheus-histograms-in-grafana/